# How can i change the header of a page if a user is logged in?

Tags: php

My code looks like this so far:

```
<?php
session_start();
//if session is not registered
if(!isset($_SESSION['Email'])) {
header("Location:createEvent.php");
}else{//if session is registered
header("includes/inc_header_User.php");
}
?>
```

I want to keep the header for each page as: inc_header_User.php as long as the user is logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `include()`, not `header()` to import the contents of the file.

```
include("includes/inc_header_User.php");
```

Answer (score 2):

`header()` is used to send HEADER information to the browser. I believe your second `header()` statement should really be `include()`, which includes other PHP files into the current script.

Answer (score 0):

That would be included twice once for the header and another time for the footer in order to change either or both of them.

```
<?php
session_start();
//if session is not registered
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
include("footer.php");
}else{//if session is registered
Include("footer_inside.php");
}
?>
```